# message.client.guilds.fetch() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's the relevant snippet of the code I was working on:

```js
message.client.guilds.fetch('ID Here', false).then(guild => message.channel.send(guild.name))
```

---

According do the [`discord.js` docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), this function, [`GuildManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch), should theoretically work. However, I keep getting this error:

```
message.client.guilds.fetch is not a function
```

---

I even tried directly copying and pasting the example from the function docs, but it still gave me the same error.

[image: Docs Example]

I'm fairly stumped, any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I should mention that all other `discord.js` `fetch` methods are working fine, such as:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch()
```

---

Edit #2: My previous problem has been solved, I was using the wrong version of `discord.js`. However, I now get a new error:

```js
DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
```

When running it.

Comment: Please use `client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID")` instead.

Comment: @Jakye The functionality is not equivalent. `fetch` with `false` as the second argument should get the guild from REST.

Comment: @Jakye I'd like to use `.fetch()` so I can request Discord's API

Comment: @user4642212 (from `discord.js` docs): All of the guilds the client is currently handling, mapped by their IDs - as long as sharding isn't being used, this will be every guild the bot is a member of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are most likely using an outdated `discord.js` version. `client.guilds` was made a `GuildManager` as of v12.0.0 and the method `client.guilds.fetch` was added only in the latest version v12.3.0. You need to have a `discord.js` version >= 12.3.0 in order to use this method.

Try `npm ls discord.js` to check the active version in your dependencies.
Try `npm i discord.js@latest` to forcefully upgrade to latest version.

Comment: I'm currently using the latest `discord.js` version

Comment: @Lioness100 Can you share the output of `message.client.guilds.constructor.name` in your above code context?

Comment: @Lioness100 I edited the answer with some further details, finding that the `fetch` method was actually only added in this most recent version v12.3. Please ensure you really have the *latest* version and not just some other v12 version.

Comment: That would do it. I prematurely commented I was using the latest version before checking, sorry. I was using a `12.2` version. It's now returning a `DiscordAPIError: Missing Access` error, what permissions are required?

Comment: @Lioness100 `Missing Access` is not a permission error, it simply means the resource is not visible to your bot. This means you don't share a resource with it, i.e. your bot isn't in the guild you're requesting.

Comment: But isn't the point of `Guild.fetch` to get data for a guild that isn't cached?

Comment: @Lioness100 Yes. Your client will receive and cache all guilds it has access to. A guild may only be uncached in the event you're using sharding - i.e. multiple Client instances each handling a portion of your bot's total guilds. That's what this function is for. Discord does not allow users or bots to discover info about resources they have no access to, except in the case of Users or guild widgets since they may be embedded in other sites.